# Which Function Displays The Post Authors Gravatar

Tags: avatar, gravatar

I am using:

```
echo get_avatar(get_the_author_id(), 30);
```

Which works, however i am getting this notice to use:

```
echo get_avatar(get_the_author_meta(), 30);
```

Which doesn't display the authors Gravatar image, just the Gravatar default image.

> `**Notice:** get_the_author_ID is deprecated since version 2.8! Use get_the_author_meta('ID') instead. in C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\www.wpsites.dev\wp-includes\functions.php on line 2908`

So my question is, what should i use to display the posts author Gravatar?

Answer (score 4):

> Notice: get_the_author_ID is deprecated since version 2.8! Use
>   `get_the_author_meta('ID')` instead. in
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\www.wpsites.dev\wp-includes\functions.php
>   on line 2908

You aren't using `get_the_author_meta('ID');` as instructed by the `Notice`. You are just using `get_the_author_meta()`. The latter returns an empty string when I try it.

## Reference

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta

Comment: I don't want to add the i.d because different posts have different authors which is why i added the email id which works perfectly. get_the_author_meta('ID') doesn't work without adding the i.d or email.

Comment: @BradDalton : That is a hard-coded string, not a variable. You are asking for the `ID` of the author (as opposed to the "nickname" for example) not supplying it.

Answer (score 2):

When looking at the source of [`get_avatar()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_avatar/), you can see that it takes *either* `ID` *or* `email` as 1st argument:

```
get_avatar( $id_or_email, $size = '96', $default = '', $alt = false );
```

The source of [`get_the_author_meta()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_author_meta/) shows that it will return data for the following fields:

```
'login', 'pass', 'nicename', 'email', 'url', 'registered', 'activation_key', 'status'
```

As addition to @s_ha_dum answer, you can as well use `email` user meta data as 1st argument for `get_avatar()`:

```
echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'email' ), 30 );
```